# Laravel Nova nested relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

Recently I've been trying to create Nova resource which depends on the other resource which provides the information for the main resource.

I have a table **contest_entries** which has the following fields:

- id
- contest_id
- user_id

with the following relations

```
    public function contest() : BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contest::class, 'contest_id', 'id');
    }

    public function user() : BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

Also, i have a table `contest_submissions` with the following fields:

- id
- entry_id
- task_id
- comment
- approved
- declined
  with the following relations:

```
public function entry() : BelongsTo {
    return $this->belongsTo(ContestEntry::class, 'entry_id', 'id');
}

public function user() : BelongsTo {
    return $this->entry->user();
}

public function contest() : BelongsTo {
    return $this->entry->contest();
}

public function task() : BelongsTo {
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class, 'task_id', 'id');
}
```

I have no problem in fetching this data on the `index` and `details` view of Nova, everything 'just works', however, when I try to update the resource, I'm getting the error that `user()` or `contest()` is called on `null`.

I've tried the following,

```
return [
    BelongsTo::make('Contest', 'contest', Contests::class)->exceptOnForms(),
    BelongsTo::make('Task', 'task', ContestTasks::class)->exceptOnForms(),
    BelongsTo::make('User', 'user', AccountUsers::class)->exceptOnForms(),
]
```

But for some reason, Nova is still trying to fetch these relationships ever when i explicitly tell it not to.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated, because it works everywhere, except on the `update` view (`create` view is explicitly disabled since the submissions are created by the user on the frontend)

Answer (score 0):

You should also chain a `hideWhenUpdating()` constraint to it.

```
return [
    BelongsTo::make('Contest', 'contest', Contests::class)
        ->hideWhenUpdating()
        ->exceptOnForms(),

    BelongsTo::make('Task', 'task', ContestTasks::class)
        ->hideWhenUpdating()
        ->exceptOnForms(),

    BelongsTo::make('User', 'user', AccountUsers::class)
        ->hideWhenUpdating()
        ->exceptOnForms(),
]
```